# How can I get actual process name of ApplicationFrameHost.exe

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am currently building a program which generates watermarks on designated process's windows.

So far, my program works fine on most of programs since, getting name of exe file of certain window is not challenging.

However, some programs such as Microsoft Edge, Calculator do not generate windows with exe name of it's own Execution file.

All of Window Application's common behavior is that they generate windows which are originated from ApplicationHostFrame.exe.

My question is, to be short, is it possible to get actual process id or ex file name from ApplicationHostFrame.exe window.

For example, if I capture ApplicationHostFrame.exe window which is originated from Calculator.exe, is it possible for me to trace back to Calculator.exe?

I really hope to find answer soon and thanks for reading this question.